# Collapse rows by participant in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am cleaning a dataset that contains multiple rows associated with the same user, with each row representing one time point. Each column is also tied to time point, such that there is a separate column for each question at each timepoint. The rest of the cells are blank. My data looks like this:

```
name<-rbind("Ang", "Ang", "Ang", "Bot", "Bot")
timepoint<-rbind("part 1", "part 2", "part 3", "part 1", "part 2")
q1<-rbind("More likely", "", "", "More likely", "")
q2<-rbind("", "Less likely", "", "", "More likely")
q3<-rbind("", "", "Less likely", "", "")

df<-cbind(name,timepoint, q1, q2, q3)
colnames(df)<-c("name", "timepoint", "answer_t1", "answer_t2", "answer_t3")
```

Such that the data looks like this:
[image: chart representing the code output]

I need to consolidate the dataset so that there is one row per person.

I want the data to look like this:

[image: what I want the dataset to look like]

The approaches I have seen before such as widening do not work for a dataset that has timepoint specific columns. I've tried an lapply solution like this: df[,lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse=""), by=name]  but this has not worked for me.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In your example `cbind` doesn't make a `data.frame`, it makes a `matrix` - I think you want `df<-data.frame(name,timepoint, q1, q2, q3)`

Answer (score 1):

For your example you could `group_by(name)` and take the `max()` for each column, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

name<-rbind("Ang", "Ang", "Ang", "Bot", "Bot")
timepoint<-rbind("part 1", "part 2", "part 3", "part 1", "part 2")
q1<-rbind("More likely", "", "", "More likely", "")
q2<-rbind("", "Less likely", "", "", "More likely")
q3<-rbind("", "", "Less likely", "", "")

df<-cbind(name,timepoint, q1, q2, q3)
colnames(df)<-c("name", "timepoint", "answer_t1", "answer_t2", "answer_t3")

df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("answer"), max))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   name  answer_t1   answer_t2   answer_t3    
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>        
#> 1 Ang   More likely Less likely "Less likely"
#> 2 Bot   More likely More likely ""
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table...

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x) & x != ""]) , 
   by = .(name), 
   .SDcols = c("answer_t1", "answer_t2", "answer_t3")]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do

```
aggregate(.~name, subset(data.frame(df), select = -timepoint), max)

  name   answer_t1   answer_t2   answer_t3
1  Ang More likely Less likely Less likely
2  Bot More likely More likely
```

or even:

```
aggregate(.~name, data.frame(df)[-2], max)

  name   answer_t1   answer_t2   answer_t3
1  Ang More likely Less likely Less likely
2  Bot More likely More likely
```